# HighCharts : How to add click event on colorAxis in heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highmaps

I need to add **click event** in **colorAxis** of HeatMap, but API show only two events "AfterSetExtremes" and "SetExtremes".

I added the 'click' listener in colorAxis events block and expected it to work, But it didn't.

**Question:** How do i add click event on colorAxis, so when we click on color-axis bar, the event will be listened by "click" listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, there isn't `click` event available in `events`. It is still possible to add event click to a specific part of the axis. For example:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,
        events: {
            load: function () {
            var axis = this.colorAxis[0];

            axis.legendGroup.on('click', function (e) {
                console.log('Click:', e);
            });
          }
        }
    },
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ubjsgtdo/

`legendGroup` is a group with all items of the colorAxis (scale, labels etc.). If you want, you can use `legendSymbol` to get click event only on the scale (rect).

Comment: Works perfect. A little question, would this **click event** effect on other legend component in the chart? (if they are present)